# Unused classes removed

Tags: c++, gcc, g++4.9

I have the following code:

```
namespace rm {
  namespace lib {
    class Object {
    public:
      Object() {printf("Hi\n");}
    };
  }
}
```

Now I wanted to compile the class into an shared library using `g++ -Wall -Wno-unused -Werror -fPIC -g -Iinclude/ -c -O0 -o object.o object.cpp` and `g++ --shared -o librm.so object.o`. Compilation works with no problems, however after checking the resulting library with `nm librm.so | c++filt`, `rm::lib::Object::Object()` is nowhere to be found. GCC gives out no warning, even with -Wextra enabled.

G++ version is (Raspbian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2

Comment: Does the object file still have the symbol? Try to link the library with the same options you were using for compiling the object - the GCC manual states: "Additionally, you may want to use the same flags when linking the shared library as you used for compiling the object."

Comment: Do you define class methods inside a .cpp file? because it seems from your sample that your class is entirely defined in a .h file.

Comment: You might also need `-fPIC` and `-rdynamic` when you build the so.

Comment: @Jepessen in this case not, but it shouldn't make any difference, because I included the header-file in the cpp file. But it actually works when defining the methon in a cpp file, actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code defined in class are implicitly marked as `inline` (and it is not used), and so not saved in file.